Error can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column al insertar de csv a una tabla plsql oracle en Pentaho
Tengo un archivo csv el cual inserta a una tabla, pero me sale el error: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
El csv esta separados por ; y la tabla tiene los siguientes campos:
FECHA VARCHAR2(10)
DPTO VARCHAR2(4)
VTA VARCHAR2(15)
MG VARCHAR2(15)
#PENTAHO #SPOON

